# How to dereference GlobalRef?

Tags: julia

A variable `p` exists, it is created by a foreign package. I think it is a pointer to `W1`, which is created by me in the global scope.

```
typeof(p) # output: GlobalRef
p # output: :(Main.W1)
p.name # output: :W1
p.mod # output: Main
```

How can I retrieve W1, which is the value behind `p`?
In other words, is there a function `f` for which `W1 === f(p)`?

Some context for the interested: I'm trying to optimize a Neural Network and loss (together represented by the function `loss`) using vanilla Zygote:

```
for s in 1:100
    l = 0.
    gs = gradient(Zygote.Params(optimizable_params)) do 
        l = loss(X[s, :], y[s])
    end
    push!(losses, l)
        
        
    for (p, g) in pairs(gs.grads)
        p += η * g #  Here the p is coming from
    end
end
```

Comment: `GlobalRef`is a built in type of Julia, and it doesn't contain value. It only has a symbol and module, you shouldn't use it in  Zygote like this. It is NOT a pointer to W1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like that this particular use-case is a mistake. However, in general you can get the object being referred to like this:

```
julia> module X
       x = 5
       end
Main.X

julia> g = GlobalRef(X, :x)
:(Main.X.x)

julia> getfield(g.mod, g.name)
5
```